# Better way to bind nested functions in my interpreter

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I am attempting to write a interpreter that will turn a string like:

`vector(random(0, 1), 2, 3)`

into a bound function using `boost::bind` like:

`bind(&vector, bind(&random, 0, 1), 2, 3)`

The intended use is for a particle system so I want the ability to be able to pass a particle to these which is achieved by adding a lambda like:

`bind(&vector, bind(&random, 0, 1, _1), 2, 3, _1)`

These bound functions are then defined as:
`typedef boost::function<boost::any(Particle*)> bound_particle_func;` so I can form a sort of list of function calls passing each particle to this list to manipulate their behaviour and thus create an effect.

I can easily make the interpreter handle something like `vector(1, 2, 3)` but when it comes to nested functions things are getting messy and I feel like I'm bodging things.

Because the parser currently handles nested functions in a recursive manner I can't directly bind the lambda value to the embedded function.

so instead of ending up with
`bind(&vector, bind(&random, 0, 1, _1), 2, 3, _1)`
I actually end up with
`bind(&vector, bound random function, 2, 3, _1)` which doesn't pass the bound function the particle.

I don't know how to better deal with nested functions.

The actual code I have at the moment (which isn't compilable) is:

```
typedef std::vector<Token>::iterator token_it;    
typedef boost::function<boost::any(Particle*)> bound_particle_func;
Vector3 vector(float x, float y, float z, Particle* p = 0);
bound_particle_func parse(token_it& it);

bound_particle_func ParseVector(std::vector<Token>& tokens) {
        const static int arg_count = 3;
        std::vector<boost::variant<float, bound_particle_func>> args(arg_count);
        int type[] = { 0, 0, 0 };

        for(token_it it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it) {
                Token& t = *it;

                if(t.type == Type::FLOAT) {
                        args.push_back(t.float_value);
                } else if(t.type == Type::FUNCTION) {
                        args.push_back(parse(it));
                        type[args.size() - 1] = 1;
                } else {
                        throw std::runtime_error("Type error: expected float");
                }

                if(args.size() > arg_count) {
                        throw std::runtime_error("Too many arguments for function `vector`");
                }
        }

        return boost::bind(&vector, (type[0] == 0 ? boost::get<float>(args[0]) : boost::get<bound_particle_func>(args[0])),
                                    (type[1] == 0 ? boost::get<float>(args[1]) : boost::get<bound_particle_func>(args[1])),
                                    (type[2] == 0 ? boost::get<float>(args[2]) : boost::get<bound_particle_func>(args[2])),
                                    boost::lambda::_1);
}
```

The `bound_particle_func parse(token_it& it);` function just passes the relevant tokens to the appropriate function like the one above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `boost::function` or `boost::bind`. You cannot pass `boost::function` to something that needs an `int`.

Since you only need one type of deferred argument, and you need to pass it to all your functions, it is much easier to roll your own function objects.

---

An alternative that does use  `boost::function` and `boost::bind` would be to use something like that:

```
Vector3 f_vector(bound_particle_func x, bound_particle_func y,  
                   bound_particle_func z, Particle* p = 0)
{
   return vector (boost::get<float>(x(p)), boost::get<float>(y(p)), 
                    boost::get<float>(z(p)), p);
}
```

and likewise for your other functions. Numbers are represented by bound functions that just return their bound `float` argument and ignore their `Particle*` argument.

Comment: I had been using function objects but ran into a problem when trying to make it easier to add new functions by not having to write a parsing function for each function, just a generic one which is why I turned to `boost::bind` and `boost::function`